# Unit test a variable for both true and false

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing, googletest

I'm working on a C++ production code here with googletest/googlemock. I've stumble upon this idea when working with one of the function in A.cpp:

```
bool A::process_(false);

bool A::process()
{
    if ( !process_ ){
        process_ = true;
    }
return process_;
}
```

where the header contains:

```
protected:
    static bool process_;
public:
    static bool process();
```

I am stuck in a way that I can only test the function for an expected output of true or an input of false like so:

```
TEST(ATest, processVal){

    A a;
    EXPECT_TRUE(a.process());

}
```

Is there a way to test the function so that both `*true*` and `*false*` value of `process_` is passed ? So that the test covers the decision for both.
I was thinking mocking so that it can expect a call for both true and false but because it is not a function in a member of a class, I guess you can not do mocking for process_ ?
If you can, how to mock the variable?

Note: I'm on linux and gcc :) thank you !

Comment: Are you looking for a way to modify `process_` from the test?

Comment: My current target: without changing any of the production code, both true and false decision is made within the function 'process()' for the 'if statement'. In other words, testing/covers the if statement for both true and false instead of only false without changing the production code using googletest.

Comment: Check my answer, it will allow test code to modify `_process` with no change to be done in production code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Solution1:** To access any `protected` attribute/method from a test
  without modifying production code

You can easily modify `_process` even if protected, just do this:

```
class SubA : public A
{
public:
    void setProcess( bool val ) { process_ = val; }
};

A a;
SubA* pA = (SubA*) &a;
pA->setProcess( false );
```

This will work pretty well and is safe. Even if you are casting `A*` to `SubA*` which is not really valid, it will work as `SubA` objects in memory are the same as `A` objects (as `SubA` does not declare any extra attribute).

This only works because `process_` is `protected`, so you create a derived class `SubA` and use it because compiler will allow this subclass to access the protected stuff.

- **Solution2:** To access any `protected` **and even `private`** attribute/method from a test without modifying production code

Now, if `process_` was `private`, this would not work...but, `private`/`protected` is only managed by the compiler...the attributes are here in memory and you may access them even if you are not "allowed to".

It's ugly but works perfectly:

```
#define protected public
#define private public
#include "A.h"
#undef private
#undef protected

{
    A a;
    a._process = false;
}
```

This hack makes it easy to access any `private`/`protected` attributes/functions from your test programs.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you. Just so I understand, your method requires that I delete the 'bool A::process_(false);' line in my .cpp and replace it with the class 'SubA' (including codes below it), is that true? And then in the test program, ATest.cpp, I'll need to just add the '#define protected public' (including codes below it) and manipulate the value of my _process?. Is there a way so that I can modify '_process' within the test itself without ever changing the production code so that both true and false decision is made within the function 'process()' for the 'if statement'. @jpo38

Comment: No, I'm proposing two different methods to access and modify `_process`. In both cases, you don't need to modify the production. First approach (`SubA`), you declare the `SubA` class from your test code and you cast the ̀A` object to `SubA` here to. Second approach, you simply add the `#define` statements in your test code and your are done, `_process`becomes accessible from your test code.

Comment: Thank you @jpo38, I'll try this out and post the results here.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a subclass of `A`. Since `process_` is `protected`, you can use the subclass of `A to set it to`true`or`false`, before running the test.

Comment: Hi Sam, I'm trying to achieve a successful test where both true and false decision is made within the function process(). In a way in my test program, I wanted to manipulate the process_ so that the if statement receive an input of both true and false instead of only false.