# Unit testing a vector string

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing, googletest

I have this really simple line of code in my production-code(A.cpp) as follows:

```
std::string A::getString(int i) {
    return sVect_[i];
}
```

with the header as follows:

```
class A{
public:
    std::string getString(int i);
    ...
private:
    vector<std::string> sVect_;
    ...
};
```

I've been trying to test the getString() function using *googletest* but an error keeps popping out:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'char* (*)(const char*, int)throw ()' to 'int'
error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::string A::getString(i)'
```

This was my test program:

```
TEST(ATest, getString){
    A a;
    EXPECT_EQ("c", a.getString(i));
}
```

I couldn't quite grasp the workaround of the vector string and how to call it in my test program without ever changing the production code. I even use the [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346690/unit-test-a-variable-for-both-true-and-false), adding #define statements, to access the private member but still couldn't do it.

How do my test actually looks like to successfully call that function?

Note: I'm on Linux and using gcc. Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: what is `i` in `a.getString(i)`?

Comment: As I searched through the whole .cpp, value 'i' is initialized as 'int i = -1' and it is in another function where it will return the value of i. In the function it will eventually be 'i = param[paramI];' after an if statement. I've checked(cout) using the main to find out the current value of i and it is 'i=1'. Is this of any help ?

Comment: The error message makes it sound like there is some function `char* i(const char*, int)` somewhere. Maybe try with `a.getString(1)` instead and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you@KarstenKoop ,doing `a.getString(1)` compiles successfully,  but when running the test output, it results in a `Segmentation fault`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the error message is misleading. Have you defined `i` globally somewhere else? To me it looks like in the local scope because it does not know what the value of the variable `i` is, it is misbehaving in an unexpected way

```
TEST(ATest, getString){
    A a;
    EXPECT_EQ("c", a.getString(i)); //here what is the 'i' and where is it defined
}
```

Comment: It is defined in another function as `int i = -1` and it will return `i` after some if statements inside it where the last thing i is defined is here as `i = param[paramI];` . I did a cout at a main of value of i and it ouputs a `i = 1`

Comment: If `i` is declared inside another function locally it will not be visible from `TEST`. May be you need to read about data visibility local and global scope of variable first. Check [this short tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm) for start.